# Is there a type-trait to remove top-level cv and reference at once?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I just want to know if there is already one provided by the standard. I know it's easy to make one yourself

```
// for C++03, use <tr1/type_traits> and std::tr1
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct remove_toplevel{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type noref_T;
  typedef typename std::remove_cv<noref_T>::type noref_nocv_T;
  typedef noref_nocv_T type;
};
```

but I think I forgot something in there or got the order wrong, so it'd be nice to have a prepared one, if one exists.

Comment: You probably intended to apply `remove_cv` to `noref_T`, not to `T` as in your code above.

Comment: @Andrey: Woops, thanks, was a typo. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), I believe, performs this functionality.

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was something! I thought `decay` was for `array -> pointer` etc only.

Comment: That's interesting to know, good question. Here is the [MSDN description of std::decay()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361638.aspx). By the way, you can chain all your typedefs into one line to be less verbose if you really need to build your own trait.

Comment: @Xeo: Pretty sure that it's the function of `decay` to replicate template argument deduction, or something like that. `array -> pointer` is the only thing I know of in the Standard termed `decay` apart from this though, so the confusion is easily made.

Comment: Skimmed through the C++0x FDIS doc and found this quote under `20.9.7.6 [meta.trans.other]` on `decay`: "This behavior is similar to the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions applied when an lvalue expression is used as an rvalue, but also strips cv-qualifiers from class types **in order to more closely model by-value argument passing**."

Comment: Range-v3 calls this `ranges::uncvref_t`, others call this `unqualified_t`. The main issue is that `std::decay` is not exactly the same as `remove_reference` + `remove_cv`. It will work like it, untill it doesn't (e.g. when one passes `std::decay` an array).

Comment: decay does a lot of things that are completely orthogonal to removing ref and cv qualifiers. It does do that. But this answer is like someone asking how to get a drink of water and you telling them that they can use a firehose.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer combining the two functionalities since it describes exactly what the intention is:

C++11

```cpp
std::remove_cv<std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type
```

C++14

```cpp
std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
```

C++20

```cpp
std::remove_cvref_t<T>
```

Comment: Does the order matter between `remove_cv` and `remove_reference`, and if yes, which cases would produce a difference?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.